# Numerical package for backreaction in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software

I am looking for numerical packages (Python/Matlab or some common languages) that can simulate the backreaction of the matter on the Kerr black hole geometry: i.e. assume I have a given initial distribution of some matter (possibly some scalar field), **I want to know how the metric around the black hole evolve in time** (I may, at latter time, need to use the time-varying metric to extract the variation on the image of the black hole)

What are the best packages for obtaining the time-evolution of the metric in the presence of matter?

Essentially I want a package that can solve the evolution of the metric and the matter together when the initial metric is Kerr Black hole and the initial field configuration is fed in by the user. I had a look at GRChombo, it seems to possess this character, but I am not so sure.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450470/25301 & links on the subject of computing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely consider the package "Black hole Perturbation Toolkit" which is being developed by an active community of experts in gravitational waves:
https://bhptoolkit.org/index.html

It has different packages based on different platforms including Mathematica, C/C++, Python, etc.